# Every third post excerpt shows up on its own line

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to have the  excerpts on this page show up 2 per line.  However, every third shows up on its own line.  Not sure how to fix this.  This is the page:
http://emgraphics.net/nsfm/category/photos/ and the css is:

```
.hentry {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 45%;
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the widths, remove margins. The boxes need explicit dimensions to maintain the grid layout, otherwise they will flow.

```
#container {
    float: left;
    width: 713px;
}

#content { }

.hentry {
    float: left;
    height: 258px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 335px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its your width: 45% * 3 is greater than 100%.
But 45% * 2 is less than 100%, so that should work.

You might want to wrap each main entry in another div and float that.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using display:inline-block instead of floats:
[http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/][1]

Alternatively you can set a fixed (min-)height on the blocks.